# Why is robot framework OperatingSystem discerning between files and folders on copy/move?

Tags: robotframework

When I want to have a cross-platform robot test that renames an app on both windows and osx, I have to use `move file` and `move directory` because the osx app is a folder (.app) while the windows app is a file (.exe). Looking at http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/_modules/robot/libraries/OperatingSystem.html I can see that the robot framework keywords Move File and Move Directory are both using the same line to do the move:

```
shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Is there any reason why robot framework doesn't give a polymorphic `move` that works for any path just like python does?

Comment: To be clear, you're just asking for the _reason_ you can't use `file move` on a .app on OSX?

Comment: more or less, yes. but also want to understand why robot is splitting up what belongs together.

Comment: Your best chance to get an answer would be to ask the person that wrote that library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak for Robot Framework authors, but in general, the reason for not having a feature is that "nobody implemented it yet" and "not enough people wanted it yet".

You can create a `Move Anything` keyword yourself, perhaps something like this:

```
Move Anything
    ${passOrFail}    Run Keyword and Ignore Error    Move Directory    ${source}    ${destination}
    Run Keyword If    ${passOrFail}=='FAIL'    Move File     ${source}     ${destination}
```